# Деструктуризация массива, содержащего объект

Tags: javascript

Есть такая структура
[
{
"plan": 93,
"fact": 1
}
]
Как по средствам деструктуризации достать plan?

Comment: `const {plan}=array[0]`

Comment: "по средствам" - ?? -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Повторяйте общую структуру слева:

```js
const data = [ { "plan": 93, "fact": 1 } ];

const [{ plan }] = data;

console.log(plan);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое vsemozhebuty(Вы мне помогаете не в первый раз) и всем не равнодушным! Я в описании забыл написать, что рузультат нужно присвоить другой переменной. С Вашей помощью разобрался const data = [ { "plan": 93, "fact": 1 } ];

const [{ plan: pp }] = data;

console.log(plan);

Comment: @АлександрСмольяков И вам спасибо на добром слове. (Наверное, имелось в виду `console.log(pp);` ).

Comment: да, верно console.log(pp);